# injecting repositories in implementation class without using @autowired in spring data using xml

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new in spring-data  i want to try use the spring data without using `@autowired` over repositories. I just want to direct inject the Repositories through xml for that i am not able to get the repositories instance in my implementation class  from xml ,reason of using xml based configuration  is this my previous service layer and controller does not support any annotation feature so i have to just manipulate the dao layer using spring data this is my xml configuration

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


            <context:component-scan base-package="com.nousinfo.tutorial" />
            <!-- Database -->
            <bean id="datasource"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.30:3306/employee" />
                <property name="username" value="***" />
                <property name="password" value="*****" />
            </bean>

            <!-- Entity Manager -->
            <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EmployeeApp" />
            </bean>

            <!-- Transaction Manager -->
            <beanid="transactionManager"                                                                               class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
            </bean>

    <!--- here i having problem on injecting the bean of employeeRepositories---->
            <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.repository.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl">
                <property name="employeeRepository" ref="employeeRepository" />
            </bean>
   <bean id="employeeRepositories" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao.EmployeeRepositories"/>


            <!-- Jpa Repositories -->
            <jpa:repositories base-package="com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao"></jpa:repositories>

  </beans>
```

this is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="EmployeeApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.Department</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my Employee Repositories

```
public interface EmployeeRepositories extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    public List<Employee> findByFirstName(String name);

    @Query("FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.firstName = :firstname or emp.lastName = :lastname")
    List<Employee> getEmployeesByName(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
            @Param("firstname") String firstname);

    List<Employee> findByLastNameOrderByFirstNameAsc(String lastname);

    List<Employee> findByLastNameOrderByFirstNameDesc(String lastname);

    List<Employee> findByDepartmentId(String departmentId);
```

}

this is my implementation

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl {

EmployeeRepositories employeeRepositories ;

public void setEmployeeRepositories (EmployeeRepositories employeeRepositories ) {
    this.employeeRepositories = employeeRepositories ;
}

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeRepositories.findAll();
}
```

this way i m calling the method for testing

```
 ApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("MyBean.xml");
        EmployeeDAOImpl daOImpl=(EmployeeDAOImpl)applicationContext.getBean("employeeDaoImpl");
daOImpl.getAllEmployees();
```

Exception is coming because of wrong mapping so please provide me the correct mapping i will be be thankful to u

here is my exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [mybeans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'employeeRepositories' while setting bean property 'employeeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepositories' defined in class path resource [mybeans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao.EmployeeRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.common.basemodel.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepositories' defined in class path resource [mybeans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao.EmployeeRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao.EmployeeRepository]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:52)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:948)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: @MichailNikolaev i have tried the way u told but its not able inject the repositories i m pasting my exception here please go through that and help me on this

Comment: check for updated answer

Comment: @MichailNikolaev  i have removed the following line and "  No bean named 'employeeRepositories' is defined" exception is coming

Comment: looks like something wrong with your  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao"></jpa:repositories> line.

Comment: @MichailNikolaev i don't know  what's wrong in this package i have kept all my repository interface in this package so that jpa repository scan for all available interface

Comment: @user1527637 is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
<bean id="employeeRepositories" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.repository.EmployeeRepositories"/>
```

and use:

```
        <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.repository.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl">
            <property name="employeeDAO" ref="employeeRepositories " />
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the below statement

```
<bean id="employeeRepositories" class="com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao.EmployeeRepositories"/>
```

EmployeeRepositories is an interface. You can't create a bean for an interface.

You have to provide the implementation class in the bean

```
<bean id="employeeRepositories" class="<Implementation class>"/>
```

if you are using `jpa:repositories` tag then check whether you have provided the `@Repository`
 tag in the EmployeeRepository implementation class like

```
@Repository
class EmployeeReporsitoriesImpl implements EmployeeReporsitories
```